# Initial value problem (solve for velocity)

Tags: integration, initial-value-problems

Gravity is a constant value of -10 metres per second squared.
An objects initial velocity is 10 metres per second.
Determine an expression for velocity.

So...

g = 10 m/s^2

g = v'(t)

v(0) = 10

and I need to solve an initial value problem, to determine v(t)

Would really appreciate some help on how to start this.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that $a(t) = v'(t)$, then integrating both sides with respect to $t$, time, gives us an equation for $v(t)$:

$$v(t) = \int a(t) \, \mathrm dt$$

Since, in this case, $a$ is taken to be a constant, we get

$$v(t) = \int a \, \mathrm dt = at+C = at+v_0$$

where the constant of integration represents our initial velocity, $v_0$. Here, $a = -10$ and $v_0 = 10$ (ignoring the units), so you simply plug those in.

Also, keep in mind that the only reason switching $C$ with $v_0$ is justified is that we're dealing with polynomials. Here, $v_0 = v(0) = a(0)+C = C$, so the switch is justified. Otherwise, you have to find $C$ by using $v_0 = v(0)$, where $v_0$ is the initial velocity given by the question and $v(0)$ is your function evaluated at $t = 0$.

As an extra note, this is one of the basic kinematic formulas, where a constant value for the function $a(t)$ will yield $v(t) = at+v_0$ and $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2+v_0t+x_0$ for functions of velocity and position, respectively. (As an extra exercise, maybe you can try using the exact same method here for showing how the function for position is obtained.)

Answer (score 0):

The velocity decreases by 10 meters per second every second; this is what it means for the acceleration to be -10m/s^2.

So $v(0) = 10$, and to determine $v(t)$, just consider how much time has elapsed and how the acceleration would affect velocity during that time.

Answer (score 0):

You have already set up the problem.

In other notation, you basically have that $$\frac{dv}{dt} = g$$ with $v(0)= 10$.

This is a differential equation. Note $g$ is just a constant.

Can you solve differential equations? This one is especially simple.

Hint: try integrating both sides with respect to $t$ and don't forget your constant of integration. That constant can be found using your initial condition to fully solve the IVP.

Comment: so dv/dt = -10 (because v'(t) = g, and g = -10m/s) --------
v = -10t + c (substitute initial value) --------
c = 10 --------
v(t) = -10t + 10 ------
Is this correct? -------

Comment: Yes that all seems good :)

Comment: Thank you for the direction :)